# nomachine mouse highlights not showing

Tags: syntax-highlighting, mouseover, remote-desktop, nomachine

My nomachine connection (from windows10 to Ubuntu16) doesn't show mouse/syntax highlights on server/ubuntu most of the times. (mouse hover onto highlightable objects). I use VScode on ubuntu and connect remotely from windows and hate to see the error/syntax highlighting from VS Code not working/showing in nomachine.  I have gone through all the settings few times and am thinking to switch to VNC. Before i switch, thought will ask for help here. Has anyone seen the issue and fixed it? Suggestions appreciated a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar problem with hover on highlightable objects was fixed in an earlier release of the current version 6 branch. Please make sure you are using a version of NoMachine packages on the remote Ubuntu host which is 6.1.6 or later.

Comment: Thanks @Nomachiner. It was the version issue, I have updated nomachine to latest and highlights work now. Appreciate it. Please note that I couldn't upvote as I am new to SO.